# Langchain with Chroma vectorstore - why will my files not push to my database folder?

Tags: langchain, huggingface, chromadb

I am building a HuggingFace Space with Langchain (Gradio SDK) to chat my data, using Chroma for the vectorstore.

My app runs perfectly in my space and I can tell it is answering queries accurately according to our data. However, no files are persisted into my database folder.
So it is costing much more than desired.

Here is my code regarding the Chroma bit, ingesting files from folder "data" and saving to folder "vectorstore":

```
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
import chromadb

# Load Data
loader = DirectoryLoader('./data/')
raw_documents = loader.load()  

# Split text
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter()
documents = text_splitter.split_documents(raw_documents)


# Save Data to vectorstore
persist_directory = "./vectorstore"
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=documents, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory)
vectorstore.persist()
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this problem. Am I missing something simple?

Thanks in advance for any insight!